# Using SNMP to retrieve the ARP and mac-address tables from a switch

Tags: cisco, switch, ethernet, vlan, snmp

I would like to get ARP tables from a switch to a syslog-ng server that has been set up on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS. I have read about SNMP and I know the server will act as a manager and the switch as an agent. I have details as to where the MIB is contained, and I must use the command

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c <community> <SwitchIP> .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2
```

I want the resulting arp tables to be directed to a  my server.

My problem is that I don't know where exactly to run the command, or save the output to a file.

Comment: Hi, adding information to a database is off-topic... [su] is a good place to ask if you need help modifying a database.  If you don't mind deleting that portion of the question, we can reopen it.

Comment: I have modified my question

Comment: What do you mean by "place the ARP tables into the server"?

Comment: The Arp tables will be generated by the switch, but i want them viewed from the server

Comment: What if we told you how to put them in a text file... is that ok?

Comment: Yes its acceptable

Comment: What brand and type of switch are you talking about. Availability of ARP tables via SNMP may differ per implementation. Also, is this a layer 3 switch, or are you really interested in ARP on a switch?

Comment: its a layer 3 switch cisco cat2960

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There seems to be a little confusion... you are asking about ARP tables, and you're using OID `.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2`; however, that OID actually is for the mac-address table in the switch.

I am assuming you know how to login to your Ubuntu server, and that `NET-SNMP` is installed... please let me know if you need pointers for doing this (see [this question for hints about loading MIBs in linux](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/translating-snmpwalk-output-into-human-readable-format/775/)).  Some of my examples assume you have the MIBs loaded on your server... you just need to remove the `-m <mib-name>` option in the commands if you don't have the MIBs loaded locally.

I apologize in advance for the length of this answer... I wish polling with SNMP wasn't as complicated...

#### Polling the mac-address table:

If you really want the mac-address table from the switch, then remember you have to change the community string you poll with... it should be in the form of `<commity@vlan>`... each vlan you poll needs a different community.

In my example below, the switch at 172.16.1.210 is configured with `snmp-server community public ro`, and I'm polling the mac-address table in vlan-10 with [dot1dTpFdbPort](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=true&objectInput=dot1dTpFdbPort) from [BRIDGE-MIB](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseMIB.do?local=en&step=2&mibName=BRIDGE-MIB).

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public@10 -OXsq 172.16.1.210 \
  .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2
dot1dTpFdbPort[0:6:53:fe:39:e0] 52
dot1dTpFdbPort[0:1d:a1:cd:53:46] 52
dot1dTpFdbPort[0:30:1b:bc:a7:d7] 52
dot1dTpFdbPort[0:80:c8:0:0:0] 52
dot1dTpFdbPort[38:ea:a7:6d:2e:8e] 52
dot1dTpFdbPort[80:ee:73:2f:b:40] 52
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

In the output above, 52 is the value of `dot1dBasePort`, which is a number the MIB uses to index the dot1dTp table.  To translate that into a normal interface name, you have to map that to an ifName... [BRIDGE-MIB](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseMIB.do?local=en&step=2&mibName=BRIDGE-MIB) does that with [dot1dBasePortIfIndex](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=true&objectInput=dot1dBasePortIfIndex)...

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public@10 -m BRIDGE-MIB 172.16.1.210 \
  .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.1.4.1.2
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBasePortIfIndex.52 = INTEGER: 10048
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpget -v 2c -c public 172.16.1.210 ifName.10048
IF-MIB::ifName.10048 = STRING: Fa0/48
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

Thus we know that all the mac-addresses on this switch were learned through FastEthernet 0/48 in vlan-10.

#### Polling the active Vlans:

If you're not sure which vlans to poll on a switch, you can get that information from `.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.46.1.3.1.1.2`, which is [vtpVlanState](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=true&objectInput=vtpVlanState) in the [CISCO-VTP-MIB](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseMIB.do?local=en&step=2&mibName=CISCO-VTP-MIB)...

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public -OXsq -m CISCO-VTP-MIB 172.16.1.210 \
   .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.46.1.3.1.1.2
vtpVlanState[1][1] operational
vtpVlanState[1][10] operational
vtpVlanState[1][1002] operational
vtpVlanState[1][1003] operational
vtpVlanState[1][1004] operational
vtpVlanState[1][1005] operational
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

Keep in mind that Vlans 1002-1005 are [internal Cisco Vlans](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/30589) that you should not poll.

#### Polling the ARP table

If you really want the ARP table from the switch, then you need to poll [atPhysAddress](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=atphysaddress&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true)...

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public -OXsq  172.16.1.210 \
  .1.3.6.1.2.1.3.1.1.2
atPhysAddress[10][1.172.16.1.5] "80 EE 73 2F 0B 40 "
atPhysAddress[10][1.172.16.1.25] "38 EA A7 6D 2E 8E "
atPhysAddress[10][1.172.16.1.32] "BC 51 FE 50 16 F8 "
atPhysAddress[10][1.172.16.1.200] "00 06 53 FE 39 E0 "
atPhysAddress[10][1.172.16.1.210] "00 18 BA 51 5B 41 "
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

#### Saving command output to a file

We're delving into areas that go outside the normal scope of this site, but to save the ARP table above to a file in `/tmp/S01_ARP.txt`, the you'd add `> /tmp/S01_ARP.txt` to the end of the `snmpbulkwalk` above...

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public -OXsq  172.16.1.210 \
      .1.3.6.1.2.1.3.1.1.2 > /tmp/S01_ARP.txt
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ cat /tmp/S01_ARP.txt
atPhysAddress[10][1.172.16.1.5] "80 EE 73 2F 0B 40 "
atPhysAddress[10][1.172.16.1.25] "38 EA A7 6D 2E 8E "
atPhysAddress[10][1.172.16.1.32] "BC 51 FE 50 16 F8 "
atPhysAddress[10][1.172.16.1.200] "00 06 53 FE 39 E0 "
atPhysAddress[10][1.172.16.1.210] "00 18 BA 51 5B 41 "
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

As you see above, you can use `cat` in linux to get all output from a text file.  NOTE: Some linux distributions (ahem... CentOS) clean out the `/tmp` directory on a monthly basis.  You should use your `HOME` directory in linux to store the file.  I don't remember Ubuntu cleaning out `/tmp`, but to be safe I'd avoid storing things there.

#### Miscellaneous notes about SNMP...

If you haven't loaded all Cisco's MIBs on your Ubuntu machine, then you should avoid using the `-m <mib-name>` flags in the `snmpbulkwalk` commands.  Loading MIBs allows you to poll with an OID name, instead of the long dotted number...

---

#### Reference information:

I am including some show commands from the switch, in case you have questions about the CLI for the SNMP commands above...

```
S01#sh ver | i IOS
Cisco IOS Software, C3560 Software (C3560-IPBASEK9-M), Version 12.2(37)SE, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
S01#
S01#sh mac address-table dynamic
          Mac Address Table
-------------------------------------------

Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports
----    -----------       --------    -----
  10    0006.53fe.39e0    DYNAMIC     Fa0/48
  10    001d.a1cd.5346    DYNAMIC     Fa0/48
  10    0030.1bbc.a7d7    DYNAMIC     Fa0/48
  10    0080.c800.0000    DYNAMIC     Fa0/48
  10    38ea.a76d.2e8e    DYNAMIC     Fa0/48
  10    80ee.732f.0b40    DYNAMIC     Fa0/48
Total Mac Addresses for this criterion: 6
S01#
S01#sh arp
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  172.16.1.210            -   0018.ba51.5b41  ARPA   Vlan10
Internet  172.16.1.200            0   0006.53fe.39e0  ARPA   Vlan10
Internet  172.16.1.32             0   bc51.fe50.16f8  ARPA   Vlan10
Internet  172.16.1.25             0   38ea.a76d.2e8e  ARPA   Vlan10
Internet  172.16.1.5              1   80ee.732f.0b40  ARPA   Vlan10
S01#
```

Comment: the answer was useful, i would like to know the meaning of    -OXsq just before the ip adress

Comment: check `man snmpcmd` if you're on a Linux host and have Net-SNMP installed. Otherwise you can find this information here: http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/man/snmpcmd.html

Comment: @MikePennington: Can you comment on the OIDs ipNetToMediaPhysAddress and ifPhysAddress?  Specifically the semantic difference between these tables and atPhysAddress?

Comment: In addition to the above, you can install netDB on that Ubuntu server and get more visibility on the ARP tables of several devices. http://netdbtracking.sourceforge.net/